# Theory of obfuscation and symbolic computation

Tags: obfuscation

Are there any documents or specific texts which describe the theoretical basis for generating functionally equivalent but semantically distinct computer programs? Ideally I'm looking for documents that cover the basis of deriving symbolic instructions from discrete instructions for actual programming languages in the same vein as [KLEE](http://klee.github.io/klee/klee-files.html).

I am curious as well if there is a lower bound of complexity in the determination of if two pieces of code share some subset of equivalent consecutive states of execution i.e  state @ the instruction pointer and the contemporaneous globals, stack and heap values.

Answer (score 3):

For your first problem, you may be interested in research on [polymorphic code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_code), a subset of the functionality you describe.

For the second problem:

Determining if two pieces of code are functionally equivalent is as hard as the *halting problem*, which is a well-known *undecidable* problem -- no computer can ever solve it for all instances of the problem.

To see that, note that we could solve the halting problem by asking if the program to be tested had equal functionality to the non-halting program `for(;;);`. We're ignoring side-effects, so we don't care if the program does some other thing in the meantime -- all we care about is whether it eventually finishes.

Comment: I appreciate the comment but I am more interested in partial solutions such as those employed by static analyzers etc.